# How to write/append select output text to one file in C#?

Tags: c#, file, text, stream

So I've created a program in C# that basically tracks statistics for a baseball/softball game, and all I want left to do is create a "game log" that outputs highlight moments in the game into a file. So for instance, while I want output on the console to prompt my commands and such (and while I still want it to display the events in the game as well), I also want to write those in-game events like the pitches, balls put in play, who scores, etc. into one specific file which I designate.

I've tried using StreamWriter, but the problem(s) are:

- I can only seem to allow my text to output either to the console or the file.
- I don't want *all* of my text to output to the file, only certain events.

So, here's what an example of my code output looks like on the console (the bolded sections are what I want to be in the designated output file AS WELL as the console, the italicized sections are my input). Note that this layout didn't exactly work as I wanted it to on here, but it looks fine on my console:

```
               R       H       E       LOB
Lady Sharks     0       0       0       0
Home Team       0       0       0       0

**Top 1**, 0 outs.

1B:
2B:
3B:

**1) K. Robinson #7** -- Today: 0 for 0

Count 0-0: *b*
**Ball.**

Count 1-0: *f*
**Foul Ball.**

Count 1-1: *p*
Ball is put in play.

Enter hit type (g/f): *g*
Enter hit zone (1-6): *4*

Enter result.

Choose from: 1b, 2b, 3b, hr, g, f, sh, sf, fc, e, gdp, di, bi
*1b*

Did the batter-runner advance any extra bases?

**In play, no out.
(1-1) K. Robinson singles on a ground ball to left field. 0 out.**

                R       H       E       LOB
Lady Sharks     0       1       0       0
Home Team       0       0       0       0

Top 1, 0 outs.

1B: K. Robinson #7
2B:
3B:

**2) S. Ribeiro #9** -- Today: 0 for 0

Count 0-0: *s*
**Swinging Strike.**

Count 0-1: *f*
**Foul Ball.**

Count 0-2: *s*
**Swinging Strike.**

Batter strikes out swinging. Confirm? (y/n)
*y*

Update status of runner on 1st, #7.

Batter may have reached base on exception. Indicate how many bases traveled with
 "+" signs.

This will result in an out. Are you sure? (y/n)
*y*

**(0-2) S. Ribeiro strikes out swinging. 1 out.**

                R       H       E       LOB
Lady Sharks     0       1       0       0
Home Team       0       0       0       0

Top 1, 1 out.

1B: K. Robinson #7
2B:
3B:

**3) B. Sutton #11 -- Today: 0 for 0**

Count 0-0: *b*
**Ball.**

Count 1-0: *b*
**Ball.**

Count 2-0: *sb*
Select which base the runner attemped to steal from.
*1*

Runner steals second base. Confirm? (y/n)
*y*

**K. Robinson steals second base.**

                R       H       E       LOB
Lady Sharks     0       1       0       0
Home Team       0       0       0       0

Top 1, 1 out.

1B:
2B: K. Robinson #7
3B:

3) B. Sutton #11 -- Today: 0 for 0

Count 2-0: *p*
Ball is put in play.

Enter hit type (g/f): *g*
Enter hit zone (1-6): *3*

Enter result.

Choose from: 1b, 2b, 3b, hr, g, f, sh, sf, fc, e, gdp, di, bi
*sh*

Update status of runner on 2nd, #7.
*+*
Batter may have reached base on exception. Indicate how many bases traveled with
 "+" signs.

This will result in an out. Are you sure? (y/n)
*y*

**In play, out(s).
(2-0) B. Sutton out on a sacrifice bunt. K. Robinson to 3rd. 2 outs.**

                R       H       E       LOB
Lady Sharks     0       1       0       0
Home Team       0       0       0       0

Top 1, 2 outs.

1B:
2B:
3B: K. Robinson #7

**4) S. Van Belleghem #29** -- Today: 0 for 0

Count 0-0: *p*
Ball is put in play.

Enter hit type (g/f): *f*
Enter hit zone (1-6): *5*

Enter result.

Choose from: 1b, 2b, 3b, hr, g, f, sh, sf, fc, e, gdp, di, bi
*f*

Update status of runner on 3rd, #7.

Middle of 1

**0 runs, 1 hit, 0 errors, 1 left on base**

Due up:

1) #1
2) #5
3) #3

Press enter to continue to Bottom 1.
```

So again, I only want those bolded parts written to a file, called say, "Game 7 Log". Then I'll do one for each game so that I can keep these records of each game, pitch for pitch and batter for batter. If anyone knows how I can put these selected texts into a file without taking out any information on my console, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How do you write to the console. Simply Console.WriteLine? I would use an approach like this:

- Create a Helper Method that you use instead of a direct call to Console.Writeline
- Define a critera that says which line ("events") go to the console, and which go to the console and a file (this can be a seperate method, a bool/enum param on your method, or some characeterist of the string given to your method)

A very basic implementation looks like this:

```
public void Write(string Message, bool AlsoWriteToFile) {
  if(AlsoWriteToFile) {
    using(StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter("filename.txt") {
      s.WriteLine(Message);
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine(Message);
}
```

Comment: Ah, this just might work! I'll try it out momentarily, thanks!

So I also forgot to mention that I wanted to append to the same file instead of creating a new file each time. So that "using" function will work to stay in the same file if I do this?

If so, thanks so much! I'll try it out ASAP.

Comment: Okay so it looks like I'm close, but the only issue still seems to be the one that I just inserted in the comments below... that I am unable to APPEND to the same file that I wrote to the first time, if that makes sense. So whenever I call this method, it seems to overwrite what I had written in there before. I'm trying to find a way so that I can keep writing to the same file every time I call this method. Otherwise, this is perfect!

Comment: You just have to tell StreamWriter to append: new StreamWriter("filename.txt", true)
Also keep in mind that you want to guard this better. Eg. what happens when the file is locked, user doesnt have permissions, etc.

Comment: Beautiful! Looks like I might be able to solve it from here. If I have any other questions, looks like you're the person to ask haha. Bless you, good sir! :)